# ListBox Item visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to iterate over items in a ListBox and hide them (set not visible).  I can do this with DataGridViewRow by setting its Visible property to false.  I'm creating my own class and adding the instances to the ListBox. (Visible is not a member of my class.)  I want to do this so that if user unchecks the box I can bring the items back.  I'm trying to do something like:

```
if (checkBox_IgnoreParent.Checked)
{
    foreach (ViewItem vItem in listBox_Views.Items)
    {
         if (vItem.IsParent == true)
             vItem.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is a ViewItem in WinForms app? Do you mean ListViewItem?

Comment: Well, that's straight-forward, you hide an item by removing it.  Putting it back in the same spot is the somewhat less obvious problem.  Be sure to separate the data from the view to make it simple.

Comment: Steve - ViewItem is a class I defined to represent a View from Autodesk Revit Architecture.  Thanks

Comment: @RevitArkitek I was under the impression that the question was referring to web forms, not WinForms. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @HansPassant That could work except i was trying to use the Datasource function as well.  Remove doesn't work with Datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing my original list and then iterating over it with items i want to remove into a temp list.  Then setting that temp list as new Datasource.  Thank you all.